# create pdf from html with iframe

Tags: .net, pdf

I search a free way for creating a pdf from an html page.

the html page contain iframe, images, list, static things.

I can only code in .net. So its .net code or compatible libraries.

I try itextsharp, wkhtmltopdf, pdfSharp. Not great success.

tank you

Comment: I think I will recreate new html file without iframe and use wkhtmltopdf. but if you have any other idea.

Answer (score 1):

What was your problem with wkhtmltopdf? I use that to convert html to pdf's and have found it very good.

For example testing with an iframe it works nicely, try the command for yourself:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe test.pdf
```

this loads and converts an iframe nicely, but only as an image.

Comment: the problem is the content of the iframe. I use js for resize the iframe. but seems to not working with wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Very interesting, I have not tried such things with wkhtmltopdf before. I think your idea of recreating new html file is a safe way to go, especially if you need searchable text. Is there a way you could show me the javascript + iframe that does not work, maby in jsfiddle or pabstebin or such? I would be interested in trying it myself as well :)